# Remove duplicates in an array using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good Day, I am trying to remove duplicate element from an array using the `forEach` loop. But at this point in time i get some errors. Below are my codes

```
function removeDup(arr) {
    let result = arr.forEach((item, index) => { if (index > 1) item.shift() });
    return result;
}
```

I am not even sure if this code would work for removing duplicates because when i run it in a browser `console` i get this error

> if (index > 1) item.shift();
>                               ^
>
> TypeError: item.push is not a function

First of all, how do i fix this error and secondly would this code work for removing duplicates?

Comment: Could you share the code with the "item.push" portion ?

Comment: item is element of array which won't have push method. Define result with empty array and then do result.push in foreach.
However it looks that just checking index>1 won't eliminate duplicates.

Comment: @LucienDubois I made a mistake. meant to write `item.shift`. edited the question

Comment: No dude, item won't have shift method either. note that item is not array so it won't have array methods.

Comment: @binariedMe Thanks for pointing that out. Now i understand

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try :

```
function removeDup(arr) {
  let result = []
  arr.forEach((item, index) => { if (arr.indexOf(item) == index) result.push(item) });
  return result;
}
```

Explanaton:

first initialize result with empty array. Then iterate through passed array, check if the index is its first occurance of item. push to result array. return result array.

Alternative solution :

```
function removeDup(arr) {
  let result = []
  arr.forEach((item, index) => { if (result.indexOf(item) === -1) result.push(item) });
  return result;
}
```

Explanation :

you can avoid checking for index as first occurance by checking  if that element has already been pushed into result array or not.

Comment: obviously it won't work consistently with item being an object and not a primitive type. You might need to implement an equal function to find indexof

Comment: Nice solution. Works well. I can see you checked the `index` of each item with `forEach` loop and compared the `indexOf` that item to the `index`. Can you please explain your code?

Comment: @diagold editing to add explanation.

Comment: Alright . Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to try and go with alternative solution or if using es6, go with Tony's solution with Set.

Answer (score 2):

```js
function findDuplicates(data) {

  let result = [];

  data.forEach(function(element, index) {
    //Checks data.indexOf(1) which is 0 === 0, then push it to array
    //Now again when it checks the value of 1 which corresponds to a value of 1 but in forloop has an index of 5, so exits and duplicate values are not pushed
    if (data.indexOf(element) === index) {
      result.push(element)
    }
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(findDuplicates([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2]))
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code?

Comment: So you are looping over the array, and you are comparing whether the index of the current element in the array equals the index, push it into the new Array.

Comment: Thats actually the part i dont really understand. The `indexOf` the element in the `array` equals what `index`?

Comment: I added some notes. If still confusing, throw the code in the browser console and use a debugger to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a `Set`? e.g.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'a']                                                                               
var unique = Array.from(new Set(arr))                                                                   
console.log(unique) // ['a', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` it will return a new array set as your checked condition

> The indexOf() method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position.
>
> The search will start at the specified position, or at the beginning if no start position is specified, and end the search at the end of the array.
>
> Returns -1 if the item is not found.
>
> **If the item is present more than once, the indexOf method returns the position of the first occurence.**

```js
function removeDup(arr) {
    let result = arr.filter(function (item, pos) {return arr.indexOf(item) == pos});  
    // at first loop -> item = 1 -> so indexOf = 0 & pos = 0 -> so return data
    // at second loop -> item = 4 -> so indexOf = 1 & pos = 1 -> so return data
    // at third loop -> item = 5 -> so indexOf = 2 & pos = 2 -> so return data
    // at fourth loop -> item = 4 -> so indexOf = 1 & pos = 3 -> no return
    // at fifth loop -> item = 1 -> so indexOf = 0 & pos = 4 -> no return
    return result;
}

var d = removeDup([1,4,5,4,1]);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Okay nice one but can you please explain your code?